# What technologies are known for ultra rapid development on web?

Tags: web-applications, web, programming-languages, rad

Leaving aside if X tool/language is open/closed source, expensive or not, the "beautifulness" of the language, etc., also performance not being such an important issue, and focusing only on what technologies (IDE + language + resources + frameworks + community size, etc.), are known for allowing programmers in the most quicker way to put ideas for a web app online.

I mean, there are different focuses on different technologies, which technologies are the most RAD oriented for web apps?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at VCL.JS it’s a open source environment mostly for business application that contain the full stack .(front end,back-end, components, data-binding, database etc)

http://vcljs.com

all with a Friendly APIs

```
var qur = new V.TQuery(this)
qur.SQL = “Select * from customers”;
qur.open();

var inp = V.TDBInput(this,’itm’);
inp.DataSet = qur;
inp.FieldName = “FirstName”
```